# Frame extraction from video error

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, video

I am trying to extract all the frames from an avi video and display them. The code is given below:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import cv
import time
cap=cv2.VideoCapture('video1.avi')
count=cap.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
cap.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, count-1)
cv2.namedWindow("Display", cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Display", frame)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
cv2.imshow("Display", frame)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0
```

Is there something wrong with the code? If not then how do I remove the error?

Comment: Normally " cap.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, count-1) " sets the position of frame to count-1 numbered frame. But if I'm not mistaken setting frame position is still not working in OpenCV. And also you don't need to set any values to capture all frames.

Comment: Sorry issue seems to be solved http://code.opencv.org/issues/1419 
But still you dont need that to capture all frames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to break the loop if frame is null before imshow, and use waitKey instead sleep.

So change your code to

```
while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    if not ret: break
    cv2.imshow("Display", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(20)
```

Comment: @Prakhar Mohan Srivastava So still it's not working?

Comment: @Haris it is getting an empty frame before the video ends so I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: @Prakhar Mohan Srivastava  Try with other video also check for coutn-2, count-3 etc...here the code works fine.

Comment: cap.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, count-1) remove that line. It is setting the frame position to end

Comment: @yutasrobot Thanks a lot. Thank you! Will you be adding this as an answer?

Comment: @Prakhar Mohan Srivastava So you where not trying to access last frame?

Comment: Accept Haris's solution, it resolves the imshow error

Comment: @Haris no, the full video. I didn't know the exact functioning of the set function.

Answer (score 0):

try this code it extracts frames from video .

it works for me

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

    using namespace cv;

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        // Read a video file from file

        CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("C:\\Users\\Pavilion\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\video\\optical illusions.avi");
        int loop = 0;
        IplImage* frame = NULL;
        Mat matframe;
        Mat img_hsv, img_rgb;
        char fname[20];
        do
        {
            // capture frames from video

            frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
            matframe = cv::cvarrToMat(frame);

            // create a window to show frames
            cvNamedWindow("video_frame", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

            // Display images in a window
            cvShowImage("video_frame", frame);
            sprintf(fname, "C:\\Users\\Pavilion\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\video\\video\\frames\\frame%d.jpg", loop);

            // write images to a folder
            imwrite(fname, matframe);
            // Convert RGB to HSV

            cvtColor(img_rgb, img_hsv, CV_RGB2HSV);

            loop++;
            cvWaitKey(10);
        } while (frame != NULL);
        return 0;
    }
```